# ZF without regularity and well orderings

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

Briefly, my question is this:

Is the following true?

$ZF - Regularity \models \varphi $

where $\varphi$ is the formula in the language of set theory defined as "For all sets $A$ and $B$, if there exists a well-ordering on $A$ and a well ordering on $B$, then there exists a well-ordering on $A^B$", where $A^B$ is the set of all functions from $B$ into $A$. Clearly this statement holds in ZFC, but does it hold for ZF, even without regularity attached?

My main concern is with the question above, so the acceptance of an answer is going to be based solely on the above question. However, if you can point me to a reference about the following harder question, then that would be appreciated: How many axioms can we take away from ZFC and yet $\varphi$ still hold? More precisely, what is the smallest subset $\Gamma \subseteq ZFC$ such that $\Gamma \models \varphi$? Where should I look to find information regarding this "minimalist" type of questions? A good reference textbook on model theory is all I have in mind.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: $\varphi$ doesn't even hold in $\operatorname{ZF}$ (including regularity). In fact, we can have a model of $\operatorname{ZF}$ without a well-order on $2^\omega$.

Comment: @Stefan Interesting! Assuming that we're not considering a model of ZF, can you provide me with an example to your claim? That is, which two sets doesn't satisfy $\varphi$ in ZF?

Comment: It is CONISTENT  with  ZF that $\{0,1\}^{\omega}$ cannot be well-ordered.It is not a theorem of ZF.  It can been shown to be consistent by the method of Forcing.

Comment: @user254665 So it's not possible to show that $2^\omega$ cannot be well-ordered in ZF using elementary methods? Forcing must be used?

Comment: As far as I can tell this statement has nothing to do with regularity.  Also as far as I know, proving $A^B$ has a well-ordering if $A$ and $B$ do is just as hard as simply proving that every set has a well-ordering, so the minimal set of axioms will just be Choice plus whatever axioms you need to prove the well-ordering principle from Choice.

Comment: @Laserlose $\operatorname{ZF}$ cannot prove that there are sets $A$, $B$ that can be well-ordered, but $A^B$ cannot be well-ordered - since $\operatorname{ZF}$ is a subtheory of $\operatorname{ZFC}$ and in $\operatorname{ZFC}$ $\varphi$ is provably false. However - as others already pointed out - it is consistent relative to $\operatorname{ZF}$ that such $A$ and $B$ exist and in fact it is conistent that $A = \{0,1\}$ and $B = \omega$ do the trick.

Comment: The Axiom of Choice (AC) implies (and in ZF, is equivalent to) "Every set can be well-ordered."  AC was shown to be consistent with ZF in the 1930's by Godel. His constructible class L (definable in ZF) satisfies ZFC (=ZF+AC). Paul Cohen invented Forcing about 1962. There may be  known methods to show the consistency of $\neg$AC with ZF without Forcing. But not that I know of.

Comment: @EricWofsey How does one show that Choice is a requirement for the well-ordering theorem? Why is it not possible without choice (assuming we're only in ZFC). I would agree that regularity was a tad arbitrary in this question (I only included it because it was somewhat* hinted in a text I am reading; I should've just not included it).

Comment: @user254665 Under large cardinal assumptions $L(\mathbb R)$ is a model of determinacy and hence violates $\operatorname{AC}$.

Comment: For the equivalence of well-ordering and choice, see  Set Theory:An Introduction to Independence Proofs, by K. Kunen. Chapter 1, Exercise 9. ($ZF^-$ is ZF minus Regularity. Kunen uses  the word "Foundation"  for "Regularity".) page 43 of the 1st edition. The applicable theorem, Transfinite Recursion on ON, is Chapter 1.Section 9, Theorem  9.3 (page  25 ,1st edition.)